# Ubuntu 18.04 installed from DVD: boots fine but no Wi FI so no Internet. Ubdates seemed to install off of install system

Tags: networking, dual-boot, grub2

It looks like the install went OK and I did updates from Internet during install, but Wi FI was not installed onto HDD version.

How do I find out what I need and install it if I have no Internet access?

Can I find minimal drivers in the DVD I installed from?

What packages do I need to copy from another Linux system I have?

The system was intended to be dual boot, but it may have clobbered a Win 10 install although parted says that there is some kind of windows partition on /dev/hda. It calls the partition type Win32, which may mean that Windows 10 got clobbered. Grub does not see a Windows Partition and boots into Ubuntu 18.04 where there is no wifi.

Comment: I meant /dev/hda

Comment: I am considering abandoning Ubuntu altogether over this issue, given that no one has stepped forward with a suggestion. All I got was a nit over the type of the other filesystem type on the HDD which I can do away with. It is Windows. RIP Windows

Comment: I aplogize for the last comment. I was able to troubleshoot this down to a failed WiFi dongle and resolve the matter. I was able to update the system and install packages I wanted.